# Site not working after installing opcache

Tags: php, opcache

I just installed opcache to my server running Apache 2.2 and php 5.3 on Ubuntu. However, my site running WordPress stopped working.

Phpinfo does run however and it shows that opcache is already enabled.

I checked the Apache error log file and it doesn't seem to be providing any helpful insight about what's causing the problem.

Is there's another method or log file i can check to debug the problem?

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: chrome would say "page isn't working.. site didn't send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".. well my problem actually is i'm not getting any error in the apache log. i'm looking for a way at least to know what's the problem

Comment: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` means that Apache was able to process the connection, but no response was sent back. I don't think these kinds of errors are logged, as the error isn't necessarily happening at the Apache level. It's likely that something in PHP is failing and error reporting is turned off. Try disabling your .htaccess file first to see if anything changes. Also, just for giggles, try setting `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your wp-config file.

Comment: useful insight. disabling .htaccess doesn't help though even turning on debug for wordpress. it just doesn't return any response. i'm thinking to use the zend debugger

Comment: @Jasper were you able to find a way to debug where and/or why opcache is failing? I am also looking for ways to debug opcache related bugs